# Problemas con listas -Prolog-

Tags: prolog

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio de [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog), el cual es el de construir un predicado que dado un átomo `a` como primer argumento, un segundo átomo `s` como segundo argumento, se unifique a un tercer parámetro `L`, que contenga un conjunto de números correspondiente a las posiciones donde el átomo `a` aparece en el átomo `s`. considerando 0 como la primera posición.

Como ejemplo tengo esto:

`buscaInstanciasAtom(asa, aSaasasasa, L)` deber resultar en `L = [3,5,7]`.

Teniendo en cuenta esto hice lo siguiente:

```
buscaInstanciasAtom(A, S, L):- sub_string(S,Posicion,_,_,A), L=Posicion.
```

Pero en vez de resultar `L=[3,5,7]`, resulta en `L=3,L=5,L=7`, y no se como insertar en una sola lista, ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el predicado `sub_atom/5` en lugar de `sub_string/5`. `sub_string/5` es funcionalmente equivalente a `sub_atom/5` para cadenas, pero tú estás trabajando con átomos.

Partiendo de tu solución:

```
buscaInstanciasAtom(A, S, L):- sub_atom(S,L,_,_,A).
```

Puedes utilizar el predicado `findall/3` para buscar todas las respuestas del predicado `sub_atom/5` de forma determinista.

```
buscaInstanciasAtom(A, S, L):- findall(P, sub_atom(S,P,_,_,A), L).
```

De forma que `L` es una lista formada por todos los valores `P` que satisfacen el objetivo `sub_atom(S,P,_,_,A)`.

[**Probar predicado buscaInstanciasAtom/3 en Tau Prolog**](http://tau-prolog.org/sandbox/zNRDIdji)

Comment: amigo, usted es un dios, muchas gracias. :)